# Java getting input from user

Tags: java

I can get input from users for scan2 scanner.But scan is not generate in this code how can i get into this while loop i cannot get inputs from users for scan scanner. How can i get inputs from users for scan scanner.

```
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Register Section\nID: ");
    String id = scan2.next();
    System.out.println("Password: ");
    String pass = scan2.next();
    createAccount(id, pass, accounts);
    System.out.println("Login Section\nID: ");
    id = scan2.next();
    System.out.println("Password: ");
    pass = scan2.next();
    boolean X = logIN(id, pass, students);  
    scan2.close();

//Login succeed

    if(X){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = "";

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {    
        line = scan.nextLine();
        if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
            System.exit(0);

        int timetablestart = line.indexOf('[');
        int timetablefinish = line.indexOf(']');

        String strlistoftimetable = "";
        String command = line;
        String[] timetableslots = null;
        if ((timetablestart > 0) && (timetablefinish > 0)) {
            strlistoftimetable = line.substring(timetablestart + 1,
                    timetablefinish);
            timetableslots = strlistoftimetable.split(", ");
            command = line.substring(0, timetablestart - 1);
        }

        String[] tokens = command.split("\\s");
        if (tokens.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("something is wrong!");
            return;
        }



        if (tokens[0].equals("add")) {
            if (tokens[1].equals("O")) {

                CSDriver.addO(tokens,timetableslots,departments);


            } else if (tokens[1].equals("C")) {

                CSDriver.addC(tokens, students);

            } else if (tokens[1].equals("I")) {

                CSDriver.addI(tokens,instructors);


            } 

        }

        else if (tokens[0].equals("print")) {

            if (tokens[1].equals("S")) {

                CSDriver.printS(tokens, students);


            } else if (tokens[1].equals("I")) {

                CSDriver.printI(tokens,instructors);

            }
              else if (tokens[1].equals("Announcement")) {

                CSDriver.printAnnouncement(departments);

            }
             else if (tokens[1].equals("AcedemicActivities")) {

CSDriver.printAcedemicActivities(departments);}
             else if (tokens[1].equals("Attendance")) {

                    CSDriver.checkAttendance(tokens, students);

                }
             else if (tokens[1].equals("Internship")) {

                CSDriver.checkInternship(tokens, students);

            }

             else if (tokens[1].equals("SemesterGrades")) {

                CSDriver.checkSemesterGrades(tokens, students);
            }
        }           else 
            System.out.println("something is wrong!");


    }

    scan.close();
}   }
```

Comment: We need to see your "logIN" method. It is likely not setting the boolean X to true

Comment: line = scan.nextLine(); is not working even X= true

Comment: Please include the shortest program required to reproduce the issue. We cannot reproduce the issue with the code you have provided.

Comment: Please stop editing your post like that. I can always flag for a moderator and it will be locked to prevent you from vandalizing it.

Comment: You only need one `Scanner` object throughout your code and do not need to manually close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting anything from `scan` because you already closed `System.in` (when closing `scan2`, at the end of the "login succeed" part). You should not close it yourself, as it prevent any future attempt to read from this stream.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. There is no problem anymore

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
scan2.close();
```

You're closing **scan2** but also **System.in**, so in order to correct your problem you need to close your Scanners at the end of your program.

Move this line at the end

```
scan2.close();
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. There is no problem anymore